# Running Java code using MPI function

Tags: java, parallel-processing, mpi

I am new to MPI. I have implemented a few MPI programs using C language on windows. I want to know the way we can write C code with MPI function, is it possible with Java code? And if yes then which platform to use and what setting are required to make it run?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673826/where-can-i-find-small-opensource-mpi-applications/16674417#16674417

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few MPI Java implementations wich run seamlessly on multiple architectures. For instance, [FastMPJ](http://torusware.com/nevonproducts/fastmpj/) runs over TCP/IP, on shared memory machines, on InfiniBand Clusters, on Cray supercomputers, Myrinet/high-speed Open-MX clusters, etc... and any platform supported by Java.

Other MPI Java (MPJ) implementations are [MPJ Express](http://mpj-express.org/), which also runs over TCP/IP and shared memory, so virtually on most of the systems, and the Open MPI Java bindings.